# How to retrieve textfield value in real time?

Tags: html, forms, textfield

I am trying to find a way to update text in real time based on what is typed into a textfeild in a HTML form.

I am aware of javascript's onChange event, however this only updates once a user clicks outside of the textfeild. What I am looking for is a way to update upon each keystroke a user inputs.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with **onKeyUp** event in javascript. [onkeyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup)

Comment: is it just me or there's a delay to uppercase the string?

Answer (score 1):

`onkeyup` event is what you need

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeyup

Answer (score 0):

**Use `keypress`:**

```
<input type="text" id="textID" onkeypress="update(event)" />

function update(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

     //do whatever you want

    }
}
```

**Note:** Object `e` **(passed from text field routine)** will let you detect what ***keys*** were pressed. **For ex:** `13` is ***key code*** for `return key`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
$("#textID").on('keyup',function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
  // or what ever you want
});
```

Assuming you are using jquery